# Using a service to share data between 2 components not working

Tags: angular, typescript

Below is my `project.service.ts`

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()

export class ProjectService {
    public profskills_value = " Test ";
}
```

From `component1.ts` I am assigning `profskills_value` variable a value as shown below:

```
....
export class ProfskillsPage {

  constructor(public service: ProjectService , public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

  }

save(){
  this.service.profskills_value = this.skills;
  console.log(this.service.profskills_value);
}
...
```

Now when I try to read the value from `component2.ts` in console log, it shows me `Test` and not the one I assigned from `component1.ts` .

What am I doing wrong?

### Edit 1

Copying my complete ts files below:

`profskills.ts` where i am assigning the value

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ProjectService } from '../project.service';

/**
 * Generated class for the ProfskillsPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */
//@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-profskills',
  templateUrl: 'profskills.html',
  providers: [ProjectService]
})
export class ProfskillsPage {

  skills='';

  constructor(public service: ProjectService , public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ProfskillsPage');
  }


save(){
  //console.log(this.skills);

  this.service.profskills_value = this.skills;
  console.log(this.service.profskills_value);
}

}
```

`pinfo.ts` where I am trying to read the value, but result is coming the hardcoded value in service which is `test` and not the assigned value from `profskills.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ProjectService } from '../project.service';

/**
 * Generated class for the ProfskillsPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */
//@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-profskills',
  templateUrl: 'profskills.html',
  providers: [ProjectService]
})
export class ProfskillsPage {

  skills='';

  constructor(public service: ProjectService , public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ProfskillsPage');
  }


save(){
  //console.log(this.skills);

  this.service.profskills_value = this.skills;
  console.log(this.service.profskills_value);
}

}
```

Comment: What is the type of `this.skills`?

Comment: i have it like this `skills=' ';`

Comment: can you post total ProfskillsPage ts file

Comment: updated my question, hope it is much clear now

Comment: I think your providers: [ProjectService] needs to be put under app.module.ts, so that it will be one instance of the service for all components. see 'https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule'. Remove all other references from inside the components

Comment: worked this way, please advise is this the better way of doing it or as people are advising to use getter and setter ?

Comment: @JoeWu is correct. Everytime you give "providers: [ProjectService]" a new instance of ProviderService is created. If the same instance is required to be shared between two components, either declare it in NG module or in the Common Ancestor component of Componen1 and 2

Answer (score 2):

Remove `ProjectService` from each component add in the appModule

```
providers: [ProjectService]
```

if provide service in each module angular will creates new instance.

read below links to understand more info

[Service constructor getting called every time I use it in a component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45070091/service-constructor-getting-called-every-time-i-use-it-in-a-component/45070154#45070154)

you can follow this gudie.
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Answer (score 0):

Try using a getter and setter.

```
class ProjectService {
    private _profskills_value:string = ' TEST ';

    get profskills_value():string {
          return this._profskills_value ;
    }

    set profskills_value ( value:string) {   
    // Plugin some processing here    
     this._profskills_value = value 
    }
}
```

Comment: It has access to a central variable, just try it